# Using French Keyboard during installation

Tags: boot, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on the second partition of my PC. I have created created a bootable stick and copied the image using a program called rufus. I have modified my boot sequence and Ubuntu starts properly from the stick.

When I choose the option of installing Ubuntu, the keyboard is set to EN, but I have a FR keyboard. I have found the keyboard options, but it does not offer FR as an option. This problematic, since I have to enter keywords during the installation (Wifi, etc...).

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it stars properly, you can select the language (and so the keyboard) on the very first step of the installation, [when you choose between Install and Try without installing](http://leekaelin.co.uk/downloads/TechSpot/Linux_Guides/Ubuntu_11_10/Ubuntu_11_10_Capture1.JPG).

Selecting French on that screen will set the keyboard to French during the installation process.

Unfortunately this will also set the installation process in French, but since you have a French keyboard this should not be a problem...

Comment: I retried the installation and had the option to change of keyboard layout. I don't know what happened.